# turtle_tf_demo.launch goes wrong when replaced with c++ compiled nodes

Tags: ros, tf-tutorial, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run the TF tutorial and fist launch:

```
roslaunch turtle_tf turtle_tf_demo.launch
```

and it worked fine.

And then I noticed that the launch file would run nodes written in python. So I replaced them with the C++ ones and launched it again. However, turtle2 got frantic....

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mw2ds061oprzgx0/TF_problem
```

I've checked the C++ code of the broadcaster and listener in turtle_tf, as long as the Python ones. In terms of their functionality, there weren't any difference between the C++ and Python ones, but the demo results turned out to be a lot different.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45770/turtle_tf_demo.launch-goes-wrong-when-replaced-with-c++-compiled-nodes/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-08**:
Can you post the launch file you edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Tones answered this same issue over at [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/45884/turtle-tf-tutorial-fails-to-work/).

Basically, the API appears to have changed in the tf::Quaternion constructor with RPY as parameters to YPR as parameters. So the broadcaster is broadcasting the wrong rotation in its transform.

You shouldn't use that constructor anymore, though, as it's been deprecated.  Use something else from the [API](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Quaternion.html) to set your rotation, and make sure the order is right, and it should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-12**:
Thanks. It looks exactly the same problem. I'll try it.